# Adding border to scrollable component

Tags: vb.net

I derived a component from `System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl` and I have problems to add border property. I tried with `CreateParams` but without success, maybe I miss something?

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
        Dim params As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
        params.Style = params.Style Or &H800000 ' Turn on WS_BORDER
        Return params
    End Get
End Property

 'disable scroll bars, this part also disables my border
Protected Overrides Sub DefWndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg <> 131 Then
        MyBase.DefWndProc(m)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No, I definitely see a border, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to have a border property of true/false:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
  Get
    Dim params As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
    If _Border Then
      params.Style = params.Style Or &H800000 ' Turn on WS_BORDER
    End If
    Return params
  End Get
End Property

Private _Border As Boolean = False

Property Border() As Boolean
  Get
    Return _Border
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
    _Border = value
    Me.RecreateHandle()
    Me.Invalidate()
  End Set
End Property
```

Bob Powell has an article regarding that: [Adding a standard border to a control](https://web.archive.org/web/20141224180731/http://bobpowell.net/addborder.aspx)

Comment: Ok, the border code was ok :) like you both said, thanks for property tip. The real problem is when overriding WndProc to disable scrollbars, the border dissapears also, I guess there is some problem. Please see edited initial post.

Comment: PS. Excellent link! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved to have no scrollbars and the nice standard border property together :) Here is the code, in case anyone needs:

## Region "Disable scroll bars"

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function ShowScrollBar(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal wBar As Integer, ByVal bShow As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub DefWndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If m.Msg = 131 Then

        ShowScrollBar(m.HWnd, 3, 0)

    End If

    MyBase.DefWndProc(m)
End Sub
```

## End Region